# Trying to parse xml file but get java.security.AccessControlException in deployed GAE

Tags: java, xml, google-app-engine, saxparser

I'm trying to run a SAXParser on a GAE application on a local XML file I stored in the WEB-INF file. It works fine when I use it on development mode but when I deploy it and try to parse that file I get the following exception, and I'm not writing am XML file, just trying to parse a local one:

java.security.AccessControlException: access denied ("java.io.FilePermission" "WEB-INF/MapInfo.xml" "write")

The code I'm trying to run looks like this:

```
    @Override
public Double countPOIs() {
    Double total = 0.0;
    List<String> Coordinates;
    Coordinates = new ArrayList<String>();

    try {
        XMLParser parser = new XMLParser(Coordinates, 8);
        XMLReader reader = XMLReaderFactory.createXMLReader();
        reader.setContentHandler(parser);
        reader.parse("WEB-INF/MapInfo.xml");
        total = parser.getACC();

    } catch (SAXException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }


    return total;

}
```

The constructor seems a little strange but its irrelevant for this operation. Does anyone see any problems here?

Comment: Is reader.parse the statement that throws the exception?  It may be that the parser tries to open the file for read and write even though that is unnecessary.  If parse is overloaded with an open stream parameter then that might offer a way out.

Comment: It doesn't answer the question above but I did find one solution to using the parser for a one shot deal to upload data into the data store.

Instead of putting the xml file in your application locally place it in a drop box account, extract the link and call the parser like so:

reader.parse(new InputSource(new URL("url").openStream()));

Comment: Thanks for finding the open stream parse overload, I'll use it in an answer that avoids dropbox.

Answer (score 0):

Try replacing the reader.parse line with the following (sorry, unable to test it):

```
final javax.servlet.ServletContext servletContext = this.getServletContext();
java.io.InputStream stream = servletContext.getResourceAsStream("/WEB-INF/MapInfo.xml");
reader.parse(stream);
```